# Output Spotfire 'print' to text file

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have been struggling with something I hope to be a simple question. I would like to output values (String / Real / Stringlist) from Spotfire to a text file on my computer. My final solution would need document properties to be listed and saved, but for now let's use a working script from stackoverflow: [Is it possible to use IronPython to return the path of the current *.dxp project as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081535/ironpython-in-spotfire-current-project-path)

Two variables: path and analysis are 'printed'. How can I print those to a text file?

Something similar is done here: http://spotfired.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/export-image-from-visualization.html where a .bmp image is created.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

writing to a file isn't unique to IronPython; the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) go over this fairly well. in any case:

```
f = open('c:\\filename.txt', 'w')

f.write(path)
f.write(analysis)

my_list = ['one','two','three']

for item in my_list:
    f.write(item)    # write the item's content
    f.write('\n')    # add a line break (optional)

f.close()
```

will do you fine.

IronPython is a derivative of regular Python that can interact with .NET APIs such as Spotfire's API. thus, you can typically find non-Spotfire-specific solutions by looking at Python resources.

Comment: Hi Niko, thanks for your advice! the open() function gives the error: System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path. When i remove c:\ it runs fine (after changing writeline to write). However now I cannot find the file ''filename.txt'' anywhere. Any ideas on that :)

Comment: hi Freddy, this is what I get for writing untested code ;) I neglected to escape the \ in the file path; any \ needs to be escaped as \\. I've modified my answer. for a list of characters which need to be escaped in Python (it can vary between languages!) check https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: Thanks niko! I accepted your answer, as it gives me all information I asked for. Now ran into the issue "System.IO.IOException: Access to the path 'c:\testSpotfireOutput.txt' is denied. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\testSpotfireOutput.txt' is denied." Now I have to figure that out :)

Comment: if you are using a work PC you may not have permissions to write to C: directly. you can try a path like %TEMP% (should default to `C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Local\Temp` on Windows 7) or another known path like a folder on your desktop.

Comment: Answered the question nicely but the extra info about more resources really earned my up vote. You find so many neat solutions to common issues by knowing this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I used the following approach since I wanted to append new lines to a file. You can use for loops or other logic as you see fit.

```
#importing Streamwriter from the library
from System.IO import Path, StreamWriter

#assigning the path
filepath = "C:/Users/file.txt"

#append function 'a' being used 
filevariable = StreamWriter(filepath,"a")

# assigning first line to append to the file
linetowrite = "ABC; 123; LMN;"
filevariable.Write(linetowrite)

# assigning second line to append to the file
linetowrite2 = "XYZ; 890; PQR;"
filevariable.Write(linetowrite2)

# close file once you complete writing the file
filevariable.Close()
```