# Trying to get ironpython to create a text file that I can store info in

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio-2013, ironpython

I'm writing a gui for ironpython and I'm trying create a text file that the user can name in a textbox. The textfile is being used to give me a python script from a vector file. Any suggestions

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Thank you. I have tried using SafeFileDialog() and Spotfire(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243732/output-spotfire-print-to-text-file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following I was able to create a file with IronPython

```
ScriptEngine m_engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope m_scope = m_engine.CreateScope();
String code = @"file = open('myfile.txt', 'w+')";
ScriptSource source = m_engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(code, SourceCodeKind.SingleStatement);
source.Execute(m_scope);
```

Here's the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) about the `w+`. It opens the file for writing, truncating the file first.

So I guess you just need to insert the name of the file in the script...

Comment: Could you please mark the question as answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am putting up the code that worked for me when I was writing in python. Hope it helps.

```
def on_save_as(self, sender, e):

    dlg = SaveFileDialog()
    dlg.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt"
    dlg.Title = "SaveFile"
    if dlg.ShowDialog():
        self.save_file(dlg.FileName)

def save_file(self, filename):
    sw = StreamWriter(filename)
    try:
        buf = self.textbox.Text
        sw.Write(buf)
        self.statusbar_item.Content = Path.GetFileName(filename)
        self.openfile = filename
    except Exception, ex:
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    finally:
        sw.Close()
```